# How submit data to a rails form via a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a basic search form in my rails app that records each search that has been entered. I also want my users to be able to initiate a search with a url in the browser. E.g. http://www.example.com/searches?q=foo

I've played around with the different routing options and the logic in my controller but I can't seem to get this form:

```
<%= form_for(@search) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :search %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :search %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

To initiate a POST action on the database and submit a new search.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your form to do a GET request instead of a POST then you can use both the form and the url:

```
<%= form_for(@search), :method => :get do |f| %>
```